# my elements are not getting shifted to right

Tags: html, css

```css
.p_relative1 {
  position: relative;
  left: 100px;
  top: 100px;
}

.p_relative2 {
  position: relative;
  left: 200px;
  top: 120px;
}

.p_relative3 {
  position: relative;
  left: 300px;
  top: 140px;
}

.p_relative4 {
  position: relative;
  left: 400px;
  top: 160px;
}
```

```html
<p class="p_relative1">relative1</p>
<p class="p_relative2">relative2</p>
<p class="p_relative3">relative3</p>
<p class="p_relative4">relative4</p>
```

As per [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position) I assumed my elements will keep shifting to the right by 100px everytime I use an increment value of 100 px for `left` as give in my css snippet: ``` position: relative1;left: 100px;``position: relative2;left: 200px;``position: relative3;left: 300px;``position: relative4;left: 400px; ``` but it happens only for `relative1` and `relative2` elements.why is that so?

Comment: `100x;` `300x;` `400x;` all have a typo

Comment: sorry folks,typo fixed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is some typos in your code, write `left: 300px;` instead of `left: 300x;`

```css
  .p_relative1 {
      position: relative;
      left: 100px;
      top: 100px;
    }

    .p_relative2 {
      position: relative;
      left: 200px;
      top: 120px;
    }

    .p_relative3 {
      position: relative;
      left: 300px;
      top: 140px;
    }

    .p_relative4 {
      position: relative;
      left: 400px;
      top: 160px;
    }
```

```html
<p class="p_relative1">relative1</p>
<p class="p_relative2">relative2</p>
<p class="p_relative3">relative3</p>
<p class="p_relative4">relative4</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

In some places you have written `x` instead of `px` - please fix it (example: `100x` -> `100px` )

Comment: I already noted that in a comment. And if you feel that a typo is the reason for the problem, vote to close the question for that exact reason, don't bother answering it.

Comment: Oh ok, I'll keep that in mind in the future, thanks.